# slide local notification to load a ui alert view

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, uialertcontroller

I have written the below code for notification

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
notification.alertBody = "Do you want to extend your checkout time
notification.alertAction = "to view"
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.userInfo = ["isExtendCheckOutTime": "true"]

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

The notifications are displaying just fine, but when I slide I want to load a `UIAlertViewController` and perform some tasks.

I am completely new to swift and like to know where should I write code to get the desired behaviour. I tried in the app delegate without success.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, it is only possible when u click on actionButton.
In this way u must add

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier     identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification:  UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    if identifier == "CANCEL_ACTION" {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("actionCancelPressed", object: nil)
    }

    completionHandler()
}
```

to AppDelegate.

And Use Category with UIUserNotificationAction.
Like:

```
    let cancelAction1 = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    cancelAction1.identifier = "CANCEL_ACTION"
    cancelAction1.title = "cancel"

    let cancelAction2 = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    cancelAction2.identifier = "CANCEL_ACTION"
    cancelAction2.title = "cancel"
    cancelAction2.activationMode = .Background
    cancelAction2.destructive = true
    cancelAction2.authenticationRequired = false

    let openAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    openAction.identifier = "OPEN_ACTION"
    openAction.title = "open"

    let actions1 = [cancelAction1, openAction]
    let actions2 = [cancelAction2, openAction]

    let firstCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    firstCategory.identifier = "FIRST_CATEGORY"
    firstCategory.setActions(actions1, forContext: .Minimal)

    let secondCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    secondCategory.identifier = "SECOND_CATEGORY"
    secondCategory.setActions(actions2, forContext: .Minimal)

    let set: Set<UIUserNotificationCategory> = [firstCategory, secondCategory]

    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories:set)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

And then

```
notification.category = "FIRST_CATEGORY"
```

Otherwise you must catch this action by yourself.
But I could be wrong!)